# How can I enable intellisense in an associated config file using System.ServiceModel

Tags: wcf, web-config, intellisense

All the questions I've found referring to intellisense seem to refer to custom configuration settings. i'm trying to get intellisense on a .net standard section that's been moved out of web.config into service.config.

Is there a way?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this at all? I'm looking to do the same thing and just started searching.

Comment: Not so far, T4 could make it hacky but doable

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to have Visual 2012 or higher.   This is ensure that you have the latest schema files installed and references.

but mostly its all about how to create your root web.config or app.config file.

in your root config (app.config/web.config) you need to specify WCF service model associated config files like this

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors configSource="Configuration\behaviors.config"/>
    <bindings configSource="Configuration\bindings.config" />
    <client configSource="Configuration\client.config"/>
    <services configSource="Configuration\services.config" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

then make sure your, say, bindings.config file starts with the behaviors node

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="HoHo" messageEncoding="Text">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

using configSource can really help keep the configuration files readable.

Comment: Are there no more steps? I'm using VS2013 Professional and I don't get intellisense with the above setup